# get all columns after finding sum of Sal from a table

Tags: oracle

i have three columns employee_id,e_name,Sal and i want the sum of Sal group by employee_id and i want all the columns like employee_id,e_name,Sal,sum as out put in oracle.

in/put=                            OP=
employee_id,e_name,Sal              employee_id,e_name,sal,sum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select employee_id,e_name,sal, sum(Sal) over()
  from YOUR_TABLE
```

you will have the same value of sum for each employee

Comment: OP mentioned "group by employee_id", so I imagine you will need to make the calculation "sum(sal) over(partition by employee_id) sum_sal"

Comment: You might be right:) let's wait a comment from the topic starter.